# background-image CSS for gradient in webkit browser

Tags: css

I have CSS for Mozilla

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, 
                                       hsl(0, 0%, 20%), hsl(0, 0%, 13%));
```

and I need this CSS to work with WebKit browsers & IE as well.

Comment: `-webkit-linear-gradient` __For Safari__ ,
 `-o-linear-gradient` __For Opera 11.1 to 12.0__ ,
 `-moz-linear-gradient` __For Firefox 3.6 to 15__ ,
`linear-gradient` __Standard syntax__

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ <-- This is all you need

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you So much please add you suggetion to the answer

Comment: @SiddiqBaig You can accept Jamie's answer :) I am fine with that and you welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this **[gradient generator](http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/)**.

Example:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #BF50D8),
    color-stop(1, #70CDFF)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #BF50D8 0%, #70CDFF 100%); //Opera
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #BF50D8 0%, #70CDFF 100%); //Firefox
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #BF50D8 0%, #70CDFF 100%); //Safari & Chrome
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #BF50D8 0%, #70CDFF 100%); //IE
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #BF50D8 0%, #70CDFF 100%);
```

Comment: While that's a good starting point, it is a bit outdated and generates unnecessary code. As I've mentioned in another comment, [***IE10+ supports gradients unprefixed and IE9 does not support them at all***](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients). So the `-ms-` prefix is not needed for any version of IE. [*It was only necessary for **early** IE10 previews*](http://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/). Also, that direction is the default so it can be omitted, just like writing `0%` and `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer it should be

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient
```

Ms from Microsoft of course.

And for safari:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient
```

Comment: That is misleading. Although IE does recognize the `-ms-` prefix, [***IE10+ supports gradients unprefixed and IE9 does not support them at all***](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients). So the `-ms-` prefix is not needed for any version of IE. [*It was only necessary for **early** IE10 previews*](http://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/). At this point, all current versions of desktop browsers support gradients unprefixed (that the latest Safari for Windows is 5.1 from the spring of 2012 is another issue).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add gradient crossbrowser:

```
background: -o-linear-gradient();
background: -webkit-gradient(); /* Older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient();
background: -ms-linear-gradient();
```

Example on webkit:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(), to());
```